# Lukewarm water in bathroom

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I recently moved to a new flat. The hotwater is supplied by a electric heater located in the kitchen which is directly next to bathroom.

In the bathroom, the tap for the shower doesn’t get hot to run a bath. When turned fully hot, it’s too warm for a minute but then decreases to a temperature that it sustains indefinitely. Stopping the tap then starting again repeats this processs.

The heater can be adjust but it needs opening up. The water temperature in the kitchen (the closest outlet) seems fine.

Do symptoms point towards anything specific?

Comment: Anti-scald valve?

Comment: I can’t find anything on the tap that would allow me too open or adjust

Comment: An anti-scald valve is a safety device. Typically there is no adjustment for its maximum temperature.  They can have malfunction or break which requires repair or replacement. We can’t see your bathroom, we don’t know if you have an anti-scald valve or not, we also only have one clue about where on the planet you might be, that is your use of the word “flat”.  To answer the question asked, “yes, your symptoms point towards a malfunctioning anti-scald valve.”

Comment: If it’s unclear why where you are might be important, “local regulations and customs”.  It would also be interesting to know the age of construction, anti-scald valves are a relatively new thing in some parts of the world.

Comment: I'm based in Germany, so I'd assume there's also regulation for renovated flats here. I guess we'll have to get a plumber on the case to replace the tap.